# Modifying dynamic data like string in binary files

Tags: c++

I have a binary file that contains records of a student where each record is an instance of the class Student defined as:

```
class Student
{
   string idno, sname;
   int books_issued;
   vector<string> bname;
   public:
      void save(fstream &of);
      void load(fstream &inf);
      void modify_student()
      {
           cout<<"ID No:\t"<<idno<<"\n";
           cout <<"Modify Student's Name:\n";
           cout<<"Enter name:\t";
           cin.ignore();
           getline(cin, sname);
}
      //Some more code here
};
```

I am writing record in file using save member function:

```
void save(fstream &of)
{
    unsigned len = idno.size();
    of.write((char *)&len, sizeof(len));
    of.write(idno.c_str(), len);

    len = sname.size();
    of.write((char *)&len, sizeof(len));
    of.write(sname.c_str(), len);

    of.write((char *)&books_issued, sizeof(books_issued));

    len = bname.size();
    of.write((char *)&len, sizeof(len));
    int i = 0;
    while(len>0)
    {
        unsigned strlen = bname[i].size();
        of.write((char *)&strlen, sizeof(strlen));
        of.write(bname[i].c_str(), strlen);
        i++;
        len--;
    }
}
```

And reading records from file using load function which also returns the size of record read:

```
 unsigned int load(fstream& inf)
 {
    unsigned finalLength = 0;
    unsigned len;
    inf.read((char *)&len, sizeof(len));
    if(len>0)
    {
        char *buf = new char[len+1];
        inf.read(buf, len);
        buf[len] = '\0';
        idno= buf;
        delete[] buf;
    }
    finalLength+=(len+sizeof(len));

    inf.read((char *)&len, sizeof(len));
    if(len>0)
    {
        char *buf = new char[len+1];
        inf.read(buf, len);
        buf[len] = '\0';
        sname = buf;
        delete[] buf;
    }
    finalLength+=(len+sizeof(len));

    inf.read((char *)&books_issued, sizeof(books_issued
    finalLength+=(sizeof(books_issued));

    bname.erase(bname.begin(), bname.end());
    inf.read((char *)&len, sizeof(len));
    finalLength+=(len);
    while(len>0)
    {
        unsigned strlen;
        inf.read((char *)&strlen, sizeof(strlen));
        if(strlen>0)
        {
            string str;
            char *buf = new char[strlen+1];
            inf.read(buf, strlen);
            buf[strlen] = '\0';
            str = buf;
            bname.push_back(str);
            delete[] buf;
        }
        finalLength+=(strlen+sizeof(strlen));
        len--;
    }

    return finalLength;
}
```

The read and write operations are performed successfully, but while trying to modify the records, it shows unexpected behaviour:

```
 void modify_specific_student()
 {
     string studentid;
     cout<<"Enter id no:\t";
     cin>>studentid;
     fstream fp;
     fp.open("student.dat", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
     student st;
     int found = 0;
     if(fp.is_open())
     {
         while(!fp.eof())
         {
             unsigned int len = st.load(fp);
             cout<<"Length: "<<len<<"\n";
             if(!fp.eof())
             {
                  if(st.searchByIdNo(studentid))
                  {
                     st.show_personal_details();
                     st.modify_student();
                     unsigned int pos = -1*len;
                     fp.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
                     st.save(fp);
                     cout<<"Record Updated\n";
                     found = 1;
                  }
            }
         }
     }
    fp.close();
     if(!found)
    cout<<"Record not found\n";
 }
```

In my view, the problem arises because the new string may be of different size and will require subsequent data(and records) to be shifted. If this is the cause, how to correct it, or if not,achieve modification of records?

Comment: Your analysis seems correct. If you want to replace records in a file, they ought to have a fixed size. Otherwise reading from one file and writing to another is a common way to edit text files, for examples.

Comment: @Bo Persson If I use this reading from one and writing to other, will not it increase the complexity way too much, coz every time I will have to store in other.

Comment: Yes, it is complex. :-) Most real systems would use a database to handle this complexity for them. Or select a record layout with fixed length strings.

Comment: @Bo Perrsson Thanks a lot :) Finally my code worked using two files.